# make: Nothing to be done for 'makefile'

Tags: java, makefile

I try to learn creating makefile for java projects. I wrote a basic class as Hello.java. Then I wrote a makefile as below:

```
makefile:
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
%.class: %.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $^

CLASSES = \
     Hello.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM)*.class
```

When I try to run this file on cygwin, and type make -f makefile, I got an error like that: make:Nothing to be done for 'makefile'. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run make with no arguments, it tries to rebuild the first target it finds in the makefile.

The first line in your makefile is:

```
makefile:
```

which defines a target `makefile`... so if you run `make` with no arguments it will try to build the `makefile` target.  There are no rules to update the `makefile` target, and that file exists, so make declares that it's up to date and there's nothing to do to update it.

I don't know why you have that line there at all, but in any event you need to make sure that the first target in your makefile is the one you want to build when you run make; here it looks like you want `default` to be first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you need add something like "javac blabla.java" below "default: classes"

Comment: I typed "javac Hello.java" (not in quotation), it gave an error as  missing seperator stop. Then I searched this error, everyone said you should type tab but I typed tab it gives the same error nothing to be done.

Comment: One thing that once happened to me is that Xcode editor automatically changed tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the same error message `make: Nothing to be done for 'makefile'`.

In my case, the problem was that a directory with the target's name existed in `makefile` directory. Changing the target's name solved the problem.